# Will _Subscribers Dataview retrieve only recent 6 months data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, sql, automationstudio, data-views

I need to retrieve 1 year data from parent Bu

i used the following query.

Select EmailAddress from _Subscribers

But i got only 6 months data

Answer (score 4):

All Data Views hold up to 6 months of data:

> Query data views using Automation Studio for up to six months of
> Marketing Cloud subscriber and journey information.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5

To get more, you would either have to work with [Tracking Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5) or the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/sentevent.html), which allows you to pull historic data since the account inception.

How to use Tracking Extracts:

> You can create a data extract activity in Marketing Cloud Automation
> Studio using the Extract Type dropdown. To specify the data you want
> to include, configure the tracking extract fields. See the example at
> the end of this section for a categorization of extraction objects.
> When you’ve configured it, start your activity to produce results.

[image]

Note, that you can only get up to 30 days in a specific time range at one time, so to get 6 months of data you will have to configure and pull the data 6 times.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract_config.htm&type=5

If you're looking to get this data programatically, here's an article on using WSProxy to get all the tracking data since account inception: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/09/retrieve-tracking-data-since-account-inception-using-wsproxy/